# What this JavaScript code doing?

Tags: javascript

I have this code in JavaScript:

```
var JSON;
JSON||(JSON={});
```

Can you tell what this code is doing?

Comment: If that's the snippet exactly, then it's a very roundabout way of doing `var JSON = {};`, which creates a new object and assigns it to the variable `JSON`.

Answer (score 4):

`var JSON` is declaring a global (or other scope) variable.

`JSON||(JSON={});`  is first checking to see if JSON evaluates to true or false, and if false, then JSON is set to an empty object;

Comment: It doesn't check to see if it has a value. It could have `false`, `0`, `""` or a number of other things and still get an empty object assigned.

Comment: @Quentin - oops "has a value, if not" should have been "evaluates to true or false, and if false"

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty pointless in that context,

```
var JSON;
```

creates a variable named `JSON`

The  second part,

```
JSON||(JSON={});
```

is equivalent to

```
if(!JSON){
    JSON = {};
}
```

This can all be skipped and written as

```
var JSON = {};
```

Comment: If you skip the test, then you will always overwrite whatever it contains. That's usually Not A Good Thing in any case where someone has bothered to check if the variable has a truthy value.

Comment: @Quentin that only applies if there is more code before the set, which there is not.

Comment: — I think that assuming the code in the question represents the complete program is probably unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

It scopes a variable called `JSON`, then uses the shortcircuit nature of the `||` operator to assign an empty object to said variable unless that variable has a truthy value.

Comment: @Robotsushi - thats what its called. theres also falsey.

Comment: @Robotsushi: Isn't that the official term?

Comment: I just don't hear those expression used often enough =D

Comment: @DanielA.White: I thought it was "falsy." :)

Answer (score 0):

Its just making `JSON` an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

I think this says : if the var 'JSON' is null create a blank javascript obect.

Comment: No. It tests if it is `null` or `undefined` or any other falsy value. and if it is it assigns a JavaScript object. There is no JSON there (except as the name of a poorly named variable).

Answer (score 0):

This code is doing the following:

1. Declare variable `JSON` (`JSON === undefined`)
2. Assign an empty object (`{}`) to `JSON` if `JSON` is a falsey value.

Falsey values include: `null`, `undefined`, `""` (empty string), `0`, `NaN`, `false`.

`JSON` has been declared via `var JSON`, so is set to `undefined`, meaning that the right hand-side of the operation `JSON||...` *will be* executed. In other words, all the code is achieving is:

```
var JSON = {};
```

Comment: It scopes the variable. It might have a value from somewhere else.

Comment: @Quentin, Exactly -- the value must be `undefined` because the variable is declared via `var JSON`. If it had another value prior to that declaration it won't matter since `JSON||..` runs after that.

Comment: — No, `var` gets hosted and doesn't reset a variable with a value defined earlier in the scope. I've seen: `function (foo) { var foo … }` a number of times. The `var` is redundant because arguments are locally scoped automatically.

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't think of the case where the var would have already been defined in the same scope.